# Exchange 2019 EWS error: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

i am trying to connect to an Exchange 2019 using the EWS managed API. The connection already worked to Exchange 2010, 2013, 2016 and Office 365 (Exchange Online).

I have no idea why it doesn't work with Exchange 2019. I was currently able to test with two servers. It didn't work with either.

The error message is:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on a send
```

Maybe someone can help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2019 enforces TLS 1.2 I would suggest you try adding

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

which usually fixes that issue